# Is there any ability to count edits?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

How to know how many post I've edited? Is there any ability to say that in this web site?

Also, how many accepted and how many rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This are a couple of pretty handy queries on Data.SE:

- http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/195938/whats-your-rank-in-edits-per-user
- http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/190297/suggested-edit-rejections-for-user

Punch your user ID (181205 in your case) into those and the first will tell you how many edits you have (and where you rank). The second will show you your rejected suggestions.

You're ranked 351 with 78 edits, 2 rejections.

Comment: both are true but u did first

Comment: @alex Though you should note that the data in Data.SE is updated only periodically (I think it's once a week). So your recent edits will not be available there.

Comment: Yup. ["The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC."](http://data.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 5):

I look for Revisions in my Activity/Revisions page under my profile, oddly enough it's a different number from the data.se query Oli just posted.

[image]

Comment: It is different than the one in Data.SE because data there is not updated frequently. (I think it's once a week)

Comment: I think it's more than 2 days out. It's out by around 7000.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check those stats, is to re-visit a suggested edit you already posted.

For example, you [suggested this edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/265976).

In the top, click on `(more)`, and you will be able to see stats about you and the reviewers.

At the moment it's

> alex had 18 edit suggestions approved, and 9 edit suggestions rejected

You can reach that page by going to your profile, click on `Activity` and then `Suggestions`.

Finally click on any of the `suggested edit` link in the list.

[image]